# App reboots endlessly in Chrome 91 with cookies error in 'issues'

Tags: angular, google-chrome, cookies, samesite

I develope web app, and yesterday faced issue related with cookies. Earlier our team dealth with it just disabling `Cookies without SameSite must be secure` and adding XSRF-TOKEN in cookies.

I red (https://www.chromium.org/updates/same-site/test-debug) this flag was removed in Chrome 91 and now my app reboots endlessly and apears cookies error in issues. Are there any workarounds or how I can resolve this issue?

**Screenshot**
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WmwnM.png)

Answer (score 1):

```
open -a 'Google Chrome' --args --disable-features=SameSiteByDefaultCookies,CookiesWithoutSameSiteMustBeSecure
```

This should solve your problem temporarily.

Answer (score 1):

Since Chrome 91, the tags #same-site-by-default-cookies and #cookies-without-same-site-must-be-secure have been removed from chrome://flags. You can right-click on the Chrome shortcut, Click "Properties". Add --disable-features=SameSiteByDefaultCookies,CookiesWithoutSameSiteMustBeSecure at the end of the "Target" attribute, and then restart the browser.